# ReactNative Touchableopacity, opacity reset delayed on touch release

Tags: android, react-native, opacity, touchableopacity

I have a problem using TouchableOpacity with the code below.
when I press and release "Button 1" the opacity takes a few seconds to return to normal; besides, it seems the rendering of whole app is halt, because if I rotate my device, the screen does not get re-layout until a few seconds later.
but if I press and release "Button 2", the opacity returns to normal immediately.

Would anyone please let me know what should I do to solve this?

Thanks.

```
class someComponent extends Component {
   buttonPressed() {console.log(arguments);}

   render() {
       // something
       return (
           <View style={styles.container1}>
               <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.buttonPressed}>
                   <Text style={styles.button}>Button1</Text>
               </TouchableOpacity>
               <TouchableOpacity onPress={()={console.log(arguments);}}>
                   <Text style={styles.button}>Button2</Text>
               </TouchableOpacity>
           </View>);}
```

devices used for testing: Samsung GSII: Android 4.1.2, (some tablet): Android 4.1.1

Comment: Do you have your debugger on?

Comment: @MattAft  I've tried debug build with remote debug off and also tried release build, all have the same problem. thanks.